# Create a view in django

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

Very new to django. I'm using version 1.5.2 and I just did a fresh install. I'm using the django development server; I'll be moving to Apache down the road, but I want to understand the django's particular flavor of MVC methodology before doing taking that step.

So I start up the django server with `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000' through the terminal in my project directory (django_books). I get this error:

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /
Could not import django_books.views.home. Parent module django_books.views does not exist.
```

So my view doesn't exist. My view.py file is empty because the tutorial I was following did not include one. I'm not sure if this is the problem. If it is, how do I create this file (what goes in it)?

Directory Structure:

```
django_books
    beer (from the tutorial lol)
        migrations
        __init__.py
        models.py
        views.py
    random_book
        (same as beer above)
    django_books (this is my actual django project, beer and random_book are apps)
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    media
    .gitignore
    manage.py
    requirements.txt (output from pip freeze command)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # Examples:
        url(r'^$', 'django_books.views.home', name='home'),
        # url(r'^django_books/', include('django_books.foo.urls')),

        # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
        # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

        # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep your urls.py the way it is, that means you need to create views.py within /django_books/django_books/

Within that file, create a new function called `home`.

Alternately, if you have any functions inside of /django_books/beer/, you could reference them from urls.py.

All urls.py does is expose a python path to a function and route a URL there. So you can see that you don't have a module or file called views within django_books/django_books, which is why you get the failure.

Comment: The problem was the tutorial did not say I needed to create this view file. And you anticipated that I would ask in which directory this does, the project or app. Good job, thank you.

Comment: No problem. It was helpful for me to understand that the 2nd parameter in the url() functions in urls.py directly maps to a python function. HTH.

Comment: @alecxe I am trying to use other tools in my django instance (Git, South, etc.) and the official tutorial did not go into that so I didn't use that one. Though I did try to find the answer there...

Comment: @jefffabiny got it. By the way, what tutorial are you using?

Comment: @alecxe http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/10/24/starting-a-django-14-project-the-right-way/

Answer (score 1):

View is basically a python function that receives `HTTP Request` and returns `HTTP Response`.

Quote from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/):

> A view function, or view for short, is simply a Python function that
>   takes a Web request and returns a Web response. This response can be
>   the HTML contents of a Web page, or a redirect, or a 404 error, or an
>   XML document, or an image . . . or anything, really. The view itself
>   contains whatever arbitrary logic is necessary to return that
>   response. This code can live anywhere you want, as long as it’s on
>   your Python path. There’s no other requirement–no “magic,” so to
>   speak. For the sake of putting the code somewhere, the convention is
>   to put views in a file called views.py, placed in your project or
>   application directory.

This line `url(r'^$', 'django_books.views.home', name='home'),` in `urls.py` points the index `/` of your site to the `home` view - you should create it.

Create a python function called `home` in `views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def home(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Restart your development server and visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

FYI, read the tutorial more carefully, [part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/) is about dealing with urls and views.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I tell if I have a view that exists or not? More importantly how can I create one?